# Visual Studio exit 0

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm new to visual studio. My c# program has no errors. But when I try to run the console app it shows up for a second then goes away. I looked at a thread that said to turn off Module Load Message from Tools>Options>Output Window. However, I still get exit code 0. Does there need to be something in my main to keep the console open or what could be the problem?

Comment: The code 0 means it completed successfully without any errors. So yes, you need something to keep it open as there's no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just writing to the console, it will exit when the processing is done.  Add a `Console.ReadLine()` or `Console.ReadKey()` to wait for input before closing.

Answer (score 1):

```
Console.ReadLine();
```

Put that at the end of your program.  That will keep it open.